# Cannot convert from int to boolean in java

Tags: java

I am facing some conversion issue when used this below code

```
int mode = 4;
if (mode & 1) {  // Getting conversion issue from this line
  x = 0;
  if (mode & 4 ) {y = -ry ;} else {y = ry;};
}
```

How to solve this issue? Any suggestion?

Comment: It should be straightforward... `mode & 1` is an int, and you can't implicitly convert an int to a boolean.

Comment: why don't just use `y = mode & 4 ? -ry : ry;` instead of an `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mode & 1` is evaluated to an `int` and cannot be converted to a `boolean` (which is the expected type of the expression of an `if` statement).

Assuming you wish to test whether `mode & 1 > 0`, you should write :

```
if ((mode & 1) > 0) // tests if the lowest bit of mode is 1
```

and later

```
if ((mode & 4) > 0) // tests if the 3rd lowest bit of mode is 1
```

Comment: It's a good style to test for equality instead (`!=` or `==`) as you may later add more flags and end up with `(mode & 0x8000_0000) > 0` which is wrong.